# Compare fields in line against each other

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, associative-array

I have a file as per the below;

```
             ENV_ab 1.1.11.0
             ENV_bb 1.1.11.0
             ENV_cc 1.1.11.0
             ENV_dd 1.1.11.0
             ENV_ff 1.1.11.0
             ENV_gg 1.1.11.0
             ENV1_ab 1.1.11.0
             ENV1_bb 1.1.10.0
             ENV1_cc 1.1.11.0
             ENV1_dd 1.1.11.0
             ENV1_ff 1.1.11.0
             ENV1_gg 1.1.11.0
```

- As can be seen, for each ENV there are 6 version numbers. 
- What I want to do, is compare the 6 version number for each env.
- So, ENV_(ab,bb,cc..etc) has 6 versions (1.1.11.0), I want to be able to compare ENV_AB,bb,cc,dd,ff,gg with one another and if they are all the same print just one ENV and its version. If they are not the same, print out those that are not the same & also print once the env with the same version.

Expected output from the above if All envs for file the same;

```
          ENV_ab 1.1.11.0
          ENV1_ab 1.1.11.0
```

However say there is a diffrenet version in one of the env (so change ENV_bb version to 1.1.10.0), the expected output will be;
               ENV_ab 1.1.11.0
               ENV_bb 1.1.10.0
               ENV1_ab 1.1.11.0
Is this feasible? I have researched into associative arrays but it does not seem to be the resolution for this.

Comment: why should `ENV_bb 1.1.10.0` not be printed?

Comment: Please provide more pairs of sample input and desired output. Also try to explain in more detail how the output should depend on the input.

Comment: ok sample file;      ENV_aa 1.1.11.0, ENV_bb 1.1.11.0, ENV_cc 1.1.11.0,                                   ENV1_aa 1.1.10.1, ENV1_bb 1.1.10.1, ENV1_cc 1.1.10.1, ENV2_aa 1.1.9.1, ENV2_bb 1.1.9.1, ENV2_cc 1.1.9.1.                                                             - Each ENV has three users (aa,bb & cc). The test I am trying to create is to check the version of each user for each specific ENV. If the three users for the specific env has the same version then just print any user and the version for that env. Output will be; ENV_aa 1.1.11.0 ENV1_aa 1.1.10.1 and ENV2_aa 1.1.9.1.

Comment: However, say the new file file has a different release version for one of the users in an ENV;new file; ENV_aa 1.1.11.0 ENV_bb 1.1.11.0, ENV_cc 1.1.11.0 ENV1_aa 1.1.10.1 ENV1_bb 1.1.10.1 ENV1_cc 1.1.10.1 ENV2_aa 1.1.9.1 ENV2_bb 1.1.10.1 ENV2_cc 1.1.9.1.                                                                                                                    Now we can see ENV_bb has a different version to ENV2_aa and ENV2_cc. The desired output would now be;                                                               ENV_aa 1.1.11.0 ENV1_aa 1.1.10.1 ENV2_aa 1.1.9.1, ENV2_bb 1.1.9.1.

Comment: So the second comment output is showing that because one user has a different release version that too should be printed in the output along with the other envs that have the same version.

Comment: Edit your question and put the extra information in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*IF* I understand what you are trying to do, it is this:

1. Take a file with the pattern of `KEY_dk VERSION` defines a group and where `dk` is ignored
2. Print the first line and only that line of the group.

In `awk` you can do:

```
$ awk '{split($1, x, "_")
         if (a[x[1], $2]) next
         a[x[1], $2]=$1 OFS $2 } 
       END{ for (i in a) print a[i]}' file
ENV1_ab 1.1.11.0
ENV_ab 1.1.11.0
ENV1_bb 1.1.10.0
```

The order printed is not the same as the file order since associative arrays are unordered in `awk`. If you want the output to be the same as file order, just loop through the file twice.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys ever so much for the support. I have found the answer to my question, as is below;

awk '{split($1,a,"*"); res[a[1]" "$3]=a[1]"*"a[2]" "$3; cnt[a[1]" "$3]++;}END {for(i in res) print "output: " res[i]}' file

-What this does is check ENV(X)_(y) versions individually (so checks all of ENV1 versions against each other) and will print only one line for duplicates and will also print the version if one of them is not matched against the others.

I.E. I have a file with the following;

```
    <Input File>
    ENV_aa 1.1.11.0
    Env_bb 1.1.11.0
    Env_cc 1.1.10.0
    Env1_aa 1.1.10.0
    Env1_bb 1.1.10.0
    Env1_cc 1.1.10.0
    <Input File>

    Output;
    ENV_aa 1.1.11.0
    Env_cc 1.1.10.0
    Env1_bb 1.1.10.0
```

- As you can see from the above, that for ENV one of the versions is different from the other users of that ENV. Therefore, the code will print the different version along with one of the duplicate versions. This is useful because, it will tell me what versions the users have in the DB. So now I will notice if any of the versions are different for users of the env.

Once again guys, thank you  for the support, I am a newbie in this industry and thankful for the support received.